# Javascript: Cross browser async scheduling and race conditions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cross-browser

I tested this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/hally9k/pen/PPzWNd) in:

- IE 11
- Chrome 45.0.2454.93 m
- Firefox 40.0.3

I flipped the duration of the first of the three timeout periods as denoted on the code snippet below between 0, 1 and 2 and noted the outcome in the 3 browsers.

I found a difference and also found that I couldn't explain to myself why that difference existed.

Why is chromes output different?

IE:

```
 0. 1 2 3 
 1. 1 1 2
 2. 1 1 2
```

Firefox:

```
 0. 1 2 3 
 1. 1 1 2
 2. 1 1 2
```

Chrome:

```
 0. 1 2 3 
 1. 1 2 3
 2. 1 1 2
```

Can anyone explain this?

Here is the JS snippet from the code pen

```
var obj = {
  value: 1
}

function displayValueInInputOne(obj) {
  document.getElementById('input_1').value = obj.value;
  setTimeout(function(){
      obj.value++;
  }, 0);  // <= switch this zero for a one and then a two...
}

function displayValueInInputTwo(obj) {
  setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('input_2').value = obj.value;
     obj.value++;
  }, 0); 

}

function displayValueInInputThree(obj) {
  setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('input_3').value = obj.value;
  }, 0);

}


(function(theObj){
  displayValueInInputOne(theObj);
  displayValueInInputTwo(theObj);
  displayValueInInputThree(theObj);
})(obj)
```

Comment: Chrome getting things wrong? Who'd have thought.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: My question is why is chromes output different?

Comment: I don't believe there's anywhere in any spec that mandates the sequencing of setTimeout events. Since all the setTimeouts are scheduled to execute at the same time I'd have thought any output would be valid.

Comment: The point of the whole exercise is that the time outs are not all set to execute at the same. Incrementing the delay in the execution of the first timeout by one results in different outcomes in different browsers. The logical concept of this time difference would suggest that the scheduling should be in a particular order but apparently not. I'm interested in the technical reason for this disparity between browsers rather than specs.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is not exact. That being said, the spec minimum, no matter what you set, is 4ms. Embedded timeouts up that to 10ms. The reordering you are experiencing could be:

1) Simply random.

2) A result of differences in implementing the timeout spec.

..a) Firefox does a heavy amount of pre-calculation of code, IE does something similar

..b) Chrome is more likely following the spec, their result is what I expect.